# can I add css class to anchor tag in content page when i have put those anchors outside contentplace holder in master page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, content-pages

how can I add css class to anchor tag in content page when i have put those anchors outside contentplace holder in master page...actually i want to show the current page in menu bar in a different text?

Comment: post your code, only then we can answer

Answer (score 0):

find you master page control in content page then implement the style

```
HtmlAnchor Anchor= ( HtmlAnchor)Master.FindControl("HtmlAnchor");
Anchor.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
```